# Какие ошибки при настройке favicon допущены?

Tags: html, seo, favicon

Какие ошибки при настройке favicon допущены?
Проект на DJANGO, поэтому путь указан специфично, а в остальном, какие имеются ошибки. Вроде сделал все, как говорится на многочисленных сайтах, но порой фавиконка не работает.

```
<!-- Windows -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" sizes="16x16" href="{% static 'favicon_shop/icon-16.ico' %}">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" sizes="32x32" href="{% static 'favicon_shop/icon-32.ico' %}">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" sizes="120x120" href="{% static 'favicon_shop/icon-120.ico' %}">


<!-- Android -->
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="{% static 'favicon_shop/icon-16.ico' %}">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="{% static 'favicon_shop/icon-32.ico' %}">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="48x48" href="{% static 'favicon_shop/icon-48.png' %}">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="{% static 'favicon_shop/icon-96.png' %}">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="144x144" href="{% static 'favicon_shop/icon-144.png' %}">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="{% static 'favicon_shop/icon-192.png' %}">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="256x256" href="{% static 'favicon_shop/icon-256.png' %}">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="384x384" href="{% static 'favicon_shop/icon-384.png' %}">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="512x512" href="{% static 'favicon_shop/icon-512.png' %}">


<!-- Apple -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="{% static 'favicon_shop/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png' %}">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="{% static 'favicon_shop/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png' %}">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="{% static 'favicon_shop/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png' %}">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="{% static 'favicon_shop/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png' %}">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="{% static 'favicon_shop/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png' %}">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="{% static 'favicon_shop/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png' %}">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="{% static 'favicon_shop/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png' %}">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="{% static 'favicon_shop/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png' %}">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="{% static 'favicon_shop/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png' %}">

<!-- svg -->
<link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" sizes="16x16" href="{% static 'favicon_shop/icon_svg.svg' %}">
<link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" sizes="32x32" href="{% static 'favicon_shop/icon_svg.svg' %}">
<link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" sizes="48x48" href="{% static 'favicon_shop/icon_svg.svg' %}">
<link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" sizes="96x96" href="{% static 'favicon_shop/icon_svg.svg' %}">
<link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" sizes="144x144" href="{% static 'favicon_shop/icon_svg.svg' %}">
<link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" sizes="192x192" href="{% static 'favicon_shop/icon_svg.svg' %}">
<link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" sizes="256x256" href="{% static 'favicon_shop/icon_svg.svg' %}">
<link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" sizes="384x384" href="{% static 'favicon_shop/icon_svg.svg' %}">
<link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" sizes="512x512" href="{% static 'favicon_shop/icon_svg.svg' %}">

<link rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/svg+xml" sizes="57x57" href="{% static 'favicon_shop/icon_svg.svg' %}">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/svg+xml" sizes="60x60" href="{% static 'favicon_shop/icon_svg.svg' %}">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/svg+xml" sizes="72x72" href="{% static 'favicon_shop/icon_svg.svg' %}">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/svg+xml" sizes="76x76" href="{% static 'favicon_shop/icon_svg.svg' %}">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/svg+xml" sizes="114x114" href="{% static 'favicon_shop/icon_svg.svg' %}">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/svg+xml" sizes="120x120" href="{% static 'favicon_shop/icon_svg.svg' %}">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/svg+xml" sizes="144x144" href="{% static 'favicon_shop/icon_svg.svg' %}">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/svg+xml" sizes="152x152" href="{% static 'favicon_shop/icon_svg.svg' %}">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/svg+xml" sizes="180x180" href="{% static 'favicon_shop/icon_svg.svg' %}">
```

Answer (score 0):

> Вижу всего две ошибки - неправильно указан атрибут `type` в первых двух строках после комментария `<!-- Android -->`. Там должен быть `type="image/x-icon"`

[источник](https://qna.habr.com/q/966627)